# Moving Windows to a second monitor (KDE) through terminal

Tags: window, x11, centos7, kde-plasma

KDE seems to tell X11 to keep each monitor screen separate from the other and this is preventing xdotools from moving a window to a separate monitor. Is there any other way to achieve this through a different config still using KDE?

I'm using CENTOS7 with KDE as the desktop environment, and I cannot seem to figure out a way to do this. I know it's possible because I was able to do it in gnome. Is there a work around or a solution that anyone has encountered.

One thing I noticed is there is a gui option to change screens when you right click the browser. How can this be achieved through the terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to resolve this issue, I moved back to GNOME 3 and was able to get xdotools working.